# Notebook gets stuck when fitting tensorflow BERT model on Colab and Kaggle

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, bert-language-model, kaggle

My kaggle notebook's relevent cells:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = df[["prompt_text", "text"]].to_numpy()
Y = df[["content", "wording"]].to_numpy()
assert X.shape==Y.shape, "X and Y are not of same shape"

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=3454)

print("Training data shape:", X_train.shape)
print("Testing data shape:", X_test.shape)
```

```py
# Settings
SEQ_LEN = 512
BATCH_SIZE = 32
```

```py
bert_preprocessor = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3")
def preprocess(X):
    if (X.ndim==1): seqs = [bert_preprocessor.tokenize(X)]
    else: seqs = [bert_preprocessor.tokenize(X[:,i]) for i in range(X.shape[-1])]    
    return bert_preprocessor.bert_pack_inputs(seqs, seq_length=SEQ_LEN)
bert_train = preprocess(X_train)
bert_test = preprocess(X_test)
```

```py
ds_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((bert_train, Y_train)) \
            .batch(BATCH_SIZE)
#             .batch(BATCH_SIZE, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE) \
#             .shuffle(ds_train.cardinality(), reshuffle_each_iteration=True).cache()

ds_test = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((bert_test, Y_test)) \
            .batch(BATCH_SIZE)
#             .batch(BATCH_SIZE, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE) \
#             .shuffle(ds_test.cardinality(), reshuffle_each_iteration=True).cache()

ds_train, ds_test
```

```py
def create_model():
    bert_input = {x: keras.Input(shape=(SEQ_LEN), dtype=tf.int32, name=x)
                  for x in ("input_type_ids", "input_word_ids", "input_mask")}
    bert_outputs = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/4", 
                                  trainable=True, name="BERT")(bert_input)
    drop = keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(bert_outputs["pooled_output"])
    output = keras.layers.Dense(2)(drop)
    return keras.Model(bert_input, output, name="Summary_Examiner")
```

```py
model = create_model()
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
             loss="mean_squared_error",
             metrics=[keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()])
model.summary()
```

```py
model.fit(ds_train, epochs=10, validation_data=ds_test, verbose=2)
```

**Problem**
On both Kaggle and Colab, when the notebook is running on CPU, the last cell gets stuck with this output `Epoch 1/10` and continuously fills up RAM until the environment crashes. Over 30 GB RAM on Kaggle environment.

When GPU is activated, the code just gets stuck on `bert_train = preprocess(X_train)` (3rd cell) infinitely without any output.

*The dataset size is 30 MB in total (Train + Test).*

**Already Tried**
Removed parallel processes and caching from the dataset (as seen in the code).
Tried to fit model with raw data, without wrapping it in Dataset object.
Reduced BATCH_SIZE to 1.
Removed validation data from the fit method call.
Cannot run on my Windows machine. (Tensorflow-text not supported)

Can anyone please help? I tried everything I could think of but the problem is still there.

Comment: Is your kaggle nb public?

Comment: @Innat no, its a competition notebook